# SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode inside github and codeship

Tags: node.js, github, codeship, sparkpost

I've found following error when I run `grunt test` inside my source code Github/Codeship.

In setup command inside codeship, following code are configured like that.

```
nvm install 0.12.6
nvm use 0.12.6
npm install grunt-cli bower -g
npm install
bower install -p
npm run update-webdriver
```

and test commands inside codeship;

```
grunt test
```

But that error not found inside my source code, and actually found inside github/codeship by viewing following error message given by codeship. Because those folder structure is not defined as we configure in our server. Please help me how to solve it. Thanks.

```
Using 2 x hasMany to represent N:M relations has been deprecated. Please use belongsToMany instead
>> Mocha exploded!
>> /home/rof/src/github.com/MyProjects/node_modules/sparkpost/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/boom/lib/index.js:5
>> const Hoek = require('hoek');
>> ^^^^^
>> SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
>>     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
>>     at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
>>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>>     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>>     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>>     at require (module.js:384:17)
>>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rof/src/github.com/MyProjects/node_modules/sparkpost/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/lib/index.js:5:33)
>>     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>>     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>>     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>>     at require (module.js:384:17)
>>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rof/src/github.com/MyProjects/node_modules/sparkpost/node_modules/request/request.js:9:12)
>>     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
Warning: Task "mochaTest:src" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

Comment: Try these setup commands: `nvm install 6.11.3` and `nvm use 6.11.3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Because those folder structure is not defined as we configure in our server.

This issue has nothing to do with folder structures.

Your project is currently using Node version `0.12.6` which is extremely out of date. The current LTS version of Node is `6.11.3` and the current version is `8.6.0`.

The specific issue is `SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.` which means the libraries you are using are currently utilizing ES2015 syntax or higher. The root cause of the issue is in the [Boom](https://github.com/hapijs/boom/blob/master/lib/index.js) module, which uses `const` at line 5 (and most likely other current syntax as well).

The solution for your issue here is to update the node version being utilized inside Codeship.

```
nvm install 6.11.3
nvm use 6.11.3
```

Answer (score 2):

simple way. just upgrade your node by below code:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

enjoy!